# cannot touch '/usr/local/bin/goss': Permission denied

Tags: linux, curl

I have already used

```
 curl -fsSL
```

on Ubuntu 16.04,without any problems.
If I go for

```
sudo curl -fsSL https://goss.rocks/install | sh
```

then I have

```
touch: cannot touch '/usr/local/bin/goss': Permission denied
ERROR: Cannot write to /usr/local/bin set GOSS_DST elsewhere or use sudo
```

Is this somehow related to Goss tool or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the relation to programming (it certainly would fit better on SuperUser or Unix/Linux), but the reason that you are denied the permission to do what you do is related to the user IDs your pipe components are executed under.

With

```
sudo a | b
```

you are starting two processes, the first of them piping its output to the second one. The first one (`sudo`) executes another one (`a`) and feeds its output to `b`, which is executed with you UID.

If you change the way things are done (fetching install script as "you" and executing it as root), it will probably work. But you put a lot of trust in whoever puts this file onto that web site.

Comment: Thanks,you think that I should not install it as root before doublecheck?

Comment: @MikiBelavista Yes. Doing something as root always needs extra attention.